# Can I put the MEDIA_ROOT under the STATIC_ROOT = 'static'

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

in my application I upload images, it works perfect, but my problem is that I can't refer to Media images from my media file in my templates, so I put the `MEDIA_ROOT` under the `STATIC_ROOT`, thus I can refer my images in the templates by using `{{ STATIC_URL }}` and not `{{ MEDIA_URL }}`, it works! I ask if making the media file inside the static file will make problems after? thank you

This is a part of my settings.py file :

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = 'offres/static/media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: Why can't you use `{{ MEDIA_URL }}` in your templates?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to keep the media and static files apart from each other. Every Django applications can provide static files which for deployment purposes will be collected and copied to a certain folder using `python manage.py collectstatic`. It should be better when uploads etc. will not be collected and saved twice in such a way. Imagine you have very large image or video files in your media folder...

So, use `{{ MEDIA_URL }}` as Nicolas Cortot proposes.